# not getting line items from form recognizer prebuilt invoice model

Tags: invoice, azure-form-recognizer

I have extracted invoice fields using code here for prebuilt invoice model,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=preview%2Cv2-1&pivots=programming-language-csharp#analyze-invoices

however there is no documentation regarding how to extract invoice line items. I see here that this feature was recently launched, in March 2021
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/whats-new

Could anyone please guide about how would i get invoice line items using prebuilt model?

Answer (score 0):

Please update Form Recognizer SDK NuGet to version v3.1.0-beta.4 to see invoice line items. Sample code to call SDK and get line items details is below:

```
            FormRecognizerClient client = new FormRecognizerClient(new Uri(YOUR_FR_URL), new Azure.AzureKeyCredential(YOUR_FR_KEY));

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"SampleInvoice.pdf", FileMode.Open))
            {
                RecognizeInvoicesOptions options = new RecognizeInvoicesOptions() { IncludeFieldElements = true };
                var oper = await client.StartRecognizeInvoices(stream, options).WaitForCompletionAsync();
                var rawResponse = oper.GetRawResponse();
                rawResponse.ContentStream.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(oper.GetRawResponse().ContentStream))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Raw output:");
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }

                foreach (var invoice in oper.Value)
                {
                    foreach (FormField field in invoice.Fields.Values)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Field {field.Name}: ");
                        Console.WriteLine($"    Value: {field.ValueData?.Text}");

                        if (field.Name == "Items")
                        {
                            var count = 0;
                            foreach (var lineField in field.Value.AsList())
                            {
                                count++;
                                Console.WriteLine($"     LineItem {count}: ");
                                foreach (var (lineFieldName, lineFieldValue) in lineField.Value.AsDictionary())
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"        LineField: {lineFieldName}");
                                    Console.WriteLine($"            Value: {lineFieldValue.ValueData?.Text}");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```